# Drawing path from 2 dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to use loop in order to prepare dataset for visualization with d3 but I got some problem when getting data back from loop.

Let's say I have 2 data set,

> setX = [1,2 ,3, 4, 5] and setY = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

and I create for loop to get array of coordinate x and y from 2 dataset.

```
var point = new Object();
var coordinate = new Array();
for(var i=0; i < setX.length;i++){
    point.x = setX[i];
    point.y = setY[i];
    coordinate.push(point);
}
```

and  pulling back data from array to draw with

```
var d3line = d3.svg.line()
       .x(function(d){return d.x;})
       .y(function(d){return d.y;})
        .interpolate("linear");
```

But the value of x and y data of d3line(coordinate) are always 5 and 50.
Is there a correct way to fix this?

Here is example of code

```
<div id="path"></div>
<script>
var divElem = d3.select("#path");
    canvas = divElem.append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)

var setX = [1,2 ,3, 4, 5];
var setY = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

var point = new Object();
var coordinate = new Array();
for(var i=0; i < setX.length;i++){
    point.x = setX[i];
    point.y = setY[i];
    coordinate.push(point);
}

 var d3line = d3.svg.line()
       .x(function(d){return d.x;})
       .y(function(d){return d.y;})
        .interpolate("linear"); 

canvas.append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", d3line(coordinate))
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("fill", "none");
</script>
```

You also see my example of this code on http://jsfiddle.net/agadoo/JDtqf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First (and this causes the behaviour you see), you're overwriting the same object in the loop that creates the points. So you end up with exactly the same object several times in your array and each iteration of the loop changes it. The output you're producing inside the loop prints the correct values because you're printing before the next iteration overwrites the object. This is fixed easily by moving the declaration of `point` inside the loop.

The second problem isn't really a problem but more of a style issue. You can certainly use d3 in the way that you're using it by simply passing the data in where you need it. A better way is to use d3s selections however where you pass in the data and then tell it what to do with it.

I've updated your js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JDtqf/1/) with those changes made.